# Error when running a sub query in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I am trying to join three tables using a sub query.

The result of the first left outer join is to be used with another table to get a composite view with all attributes.

I am getting an error where the compile says, Unknown Command for the table in the second join clause.

When I create two independent views and then join then it works fine.

```
(select
l.ENROLLED_CONTENT,
l.LEARNING_ENROLLMENT_LEARNER,
l.EMPLOYEE_ID,
l.JOB_FAMILY_GROUP,
l.EMPLOYEE_TYPE,
l.JOB_FAMILY,
l.LEARNING_ENROLLMENT,
l.COMPLETION_STATUS,
l.COMPLETION_DATE,
l.EXPIRATION_DATE,
l.CF_LRV_LEARNING_CONTENT_NUMBER,
l.LEARNING_CONTENT_DETAIL,
l.LEARNING_CONTENT_TYPE,
l.LESSON_TYPE,
e.id# "WK_WORKER_ID"
from tgt_workday.learning l
left outer join ods_hrmaster.employee e
on l.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.employee#) t1
left outer join ( select
    per_ids_id,
    per_id,
    id_pureid from
    ods_pure.person_ids
) t2 on t1.wk_worker_id = t2.value where t2.type = 'Employee ID';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it in a simple way. There is no need to make sub-queries as:

```
SELECT L.ENROLLED_CONTENT,
       L.LEARNING_ENROLLMENT_LEARNER,
       L.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       L.JOB_FAMILY_GROUP,
       L.EMPLOYEE_TYPE,
       L.JOB_FAMILY,
       L.LEARNING_ENROLLMENT,
       L.COMPLETION_STATUS,
       L.COMPLETION_DATE,
       L.EXPIRATION_DATE,
       L.CF_LRV_LEARNING_CONTENT_NUMBER,
       L.LEARNING_CONTENT_DETAIL,
       L.LEARNING_CONTENT_TYPE,
       L.LESSON_TYPE,
       E.ID# "WK_WORKER_ID"
  FROM TGT_WORKDAY.LEARNING    L
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS_HRMASTER.EMPLOYEE   E
ON L.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE#
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS_PURE.PERSON_IDS     T2
ON E.ID# = T2.VALUE
   AND T2.TYPE = 'Employee ID';
```

Once you use the outer joined table's column in `WHERE` clause, It will result in the same result as inner join(there is another ways to use it in `WHERE` clause though). So it is better to avoid using outer joined table's column in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( (SELECT l.ENROLLED_CONTENT,
                 l.LEARNING_ENROLLMENT_LEARNER,
                 l.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                 l.JOB_FAMILY_GROUP,
                 l.EMPLOYEE_TYPE,
                 l.JOB_FAMILY,
                 l.LEARNING_ENROLLMENT,
                 l.COMPLETION_STATUS,
                 l.COMPLETION_DATE,
                 l.EXPIRATION_DATE,
                 l.CF_LRV_LEARNING_CONTENT_NUMBER,
                 l.LEARNING_CONTENT_DETAIL,
                 l.LEARNING_CONTENT_TYPE,
                 l.LESSON_TYPE,
                 e.id# "WK_WORKER_ID"
            FROM tgt_workday.learning l
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN ods_hrmaster.employee e
                    ON l.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.employee) t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT per_ids_id, per_id, id_pureid FROM ods_pure.person_ids) t2
           ON t1.wk_worker_id = t2.VAL AND t2.TYPE = 'Employee ID')
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob,  added value and type in the inner select clause and the result came as expected :).